# Issues in extracting zip file using file manager in laravel

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I want to extract zip file from file manager and I have this errors.

PS: I use Cpanel - laravel - CMS MASTER

```
Archive:  /home/copyanc/domains/doica.ro/smartkindervilla/bootstrap-cms.zip
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/.env.example  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/.gitattributes  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/.gitignore  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/.travis.yml  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Console/Kernel.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Facades/CommentRepository.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Facades/EventRepository.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Facades/NavigationFactory.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Facades/PageRepository.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Facades/PostRepository.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Http/Controllers/AbstractController.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Http/Controllers/CommentController.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Http/Controllers/EventController.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Http/Controllers/PageController.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Http/filters.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Http/Kernel.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Http/Middleware/Auth/Blog.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Http/Middleware/Auth/Edit.php  
  inflating: bootstrap-cms/app/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php  
 extracting: bootstrap-cms/app/Http/Requests/.gitkeep
```

Comment: What errors? I don't see any errors.

Comment: I'm facing the same this kind of issue can you tell me how to fix this. because in my case this type of issue show in my multiple file and env file is also missing. please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

used to face this problem, all you have to do is remove the bootstrap-cms directory completely then extract them again

Answer (score 0):

There is no error, these messages describe the file extraction method:'inflating' or 'extracting'.

See https://superuser.com/a/211308